# ZFS with HWE kernel?

Tags: lts, zfs

For various reasons, we have to keep a server running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS for a while, but with HWE kernel.
I have now noticed that this leads to the effect that the ZFS kernel module is 0.7.5, but zfsutils-linux is 0.6.5.
Is this safe? Is there a clean, recommended way to get zfsutils to 0.7.5, too?

Answer (score -1):

I've been looking at the packages you say.

- [zfs-dkms (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu27)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/zfs-dkms)
- [zfsutils-linux (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu27)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/zfsutils-linux)

These are the ones that are available for your version.

If you install them from a PPA, it is not a good idea for a server in production.

And it is advisable to have both packages paired with the same version.

I would use the version from the Ubuntu repositories, unless you need and consider that version 0.7.3 is the right one for your server

Comment: Maybe you haven't fully understand the issue. Ubuntu offers the HWE kernel in the repositiory: linux-generic-hwe-16.04
This provides kernel version 4.15, which seems to come with ZFS 0.7.5. Since the userspace tools are not updates, the version compared to the kernel module differs.

The question is: Is that save? Should I change it, and if yes, how?

Comment: I have installed on Bionic ZFS 0.7.5-1 and I'm perfect.

For me that version works correctly.

Comment: I'm really happy for you, but we cannot go to Bionic right now.